A giant wall in the middle of the ocean that splits the world in two
I watched what I think is a couple of episodes of a series a long time ago, maybe around 2002-2004 or something. Could be an older show. The show had a medieval setting.
In this show, there was a huge wall in the middle of the ocean. It split the world into two parts. the wall has a small opening which opens periodically. People are desperate to go to the other side hoping for a better life.
They use old boats/small ships with oars to row as fast as possible to go try and cross the opening in the wall when it appears, but the width of the wall is too large and most of them get crushed by the wall when it closes. Only the Main character and his buddies get past the wall.
I vaguely remember the other side maybe had a magical element to it.
I am not sure. This was maybe a couple of episodes worth.

Some people might think that 2002-2004 was not "a long time ago".   Some people who use this site might be old enough to think of those years as recent times.

was it a solid wall, or was it a fog?

The Dark Eye uses this trope with the Wall of Efferd, separating Myranor from Aventuria. But this is not a TV show, and the purpose of the wall is to protect Aventuria from the Myranians.

@M.A.Golding I am one of those people but, frankly, that's my problem. 20 years ago is a long time. Just because I happen to remember that time clearly and was an active adult during it and it feels recent to me, doesn't mean it is not a long time ago. We need to get used to the idea that we've aged :)

This reminds me a wee bit of Shadow and Bone but rather than a solid wall the setting was "geographically divided into two regions, from east to west, by the Shadow Fold (commonly referred to as "The Fold"), a vast area of impenetrable darkness inhabited by terrifying creatures"

Are you thinking of the clashing rocks from the two-part Jason and the Argonauts miniseries (2000)...?
Jason's ship barely makes it through the narrow passage without being crushed as it closes up.



